# Gatsby StaticImage from object field vs simple string

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Anyone worked with Gatsby and StaticImages before? This is weird... check this out:

```js
const meals = [
  {
    image_url: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...",
  },
]

const imageUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/...";    
const imageUrls = meals.map(meal => meal.image_url);

return (
  {
     meals.map((meal, index) => {
        <div key={index}>
           <StaticImage
              src={meal.image_url} << Not working
              src={imageUrls[index]} << Not working
              src={imageUrl} << Working
           />
       </div>
    })
  }
)
```

The image url path is the same in all cases passed to src, yet one works but the others not. When it fails, I see this in the console:

```
No data found for image "undefined"
              Could not find values for the following props at build time: src
static-image.server.tsx:55 Image not loaded https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
```

How come one works and the other not?